# Check url via curl, and if word/text is found do something

Tags: php, curl, gettext

I was looking around for a class/function/php script that check via cURL if a text, word or html code is found in the fetch and, if the response is true, do something; if is false, do someting else. To be more clear,

```
if is found [You need to login]
do redirect:login.php
if is not found
do redirect:showList.php
```

Hope that i was clear and understandable, and hope that someone can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: why do you need curl?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. It doesn't use curl though.

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/page.html");

$search = strpos("$page", "the text we want");

if ($search !== false) {
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/login.php");
    die();
} else {
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/showList.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you jimmy. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello, i have tried the way you suggest but it returns always positive (i have inverted the logical if, and now is [if it is found, show login | else show list] ). It always redirects to login. Does it matter that the requested page is not under the same domain?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but there are some things to keep in mind about using logic operators with strpos. [Check here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: Nope...it doesn't work. Also returned always true/positive (when ===) or false/negative (when !==). What i want to do if a text appears in the page, means that you are not logged in. If the check returns false, means that you are logged in. Exists the possibility that it don't recognize the logged in user? Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. It works perfectly for me, I just tested it again. Your script using `file_get_contents` is not a logged in user itself, it's just a random robot trying to access the page. So maybe that's why it doesn't find the words. How are you testing this?

Comment: Ahahm...i got it. So, i have no way to do what i want? Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: But what is it exactly that you want to achieve? To check who is logged in? I think we need to know more about your project. Is there a database?

Comment: I want to check if is logged in or not, because i want to redirect in two different places. If it is logged in, the text "asdf ghjk" should not appear, then the user will be redirected to a page where a list is shown; meantime, if it is not logged in, the text will appear on the checking page and the user will be redirected to a page with the login form. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But your script can not check what someone else is doing simply by visiting a URL. You need to use session cookies or a database or something. Read about making a log in system.